# Customize how to open an item from the "Open Recent" NSMenu

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu

I'm populating the "Open Recent" menu with images as they are being processed in my app but when I click on an item from the list I get an error "The application MyApp cannot open PNG types" or something similar.

Where can I customize the code to specify how to "open" an image in the sense that my app can process it?

**ANSWER**
Thanks to Antwan for pointing me in the right direction.
I simply implemented the following in my delegate:

```
- (BOOL) application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your NSApplicationDelegate class needs to respond to opening of files and in order to make mac os x recognize your application being able to open such applications you need to modify your info.plist